# "Check one's balls"

Tags: phrase-meaning

Watching [**this video**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUg1t-JfAyY)(In some countries, the view restriction seems to be pressed on.),

From around 1:55

> Do you think this particular button was designed so that it only works at the same time that has been pressed. It's lunacy, OK? Did you understand? **Check my balls on this one.**

It sounds like "Believe my action for god's sake".

Am I correct in understanding this?

Thank you for time and answers to my repetitive questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I don't think that interpretation is right, and I'm pretty sure you've got a few errors in the captioning. The sentence before the one you're asking about is definitely "so that it only works **the second time** that it's been pressed" not "the same time."

The sentence you're asking about sounds like **"Do not cut my balls off on this one,"** to me, which seems more along the lines of *"Don't undermine me."* Regardless, neither is a particularly common phrase. The dialogue in this skit is intensely heightened for comedic effect.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like the "official" subtitle is auto-created. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.